# How to add padding to the leading and action icons on the AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I want to add padding to the icons on the AppBar.

I tried wrapping icons with Padding() but that only squeezes them to the allocated space--not the one I give it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      child: const Icon(
        image: Icon(""),
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
```

My app bar currently looks like this

[image]

With the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      leading: RedBlock(),
      actions: [YellowBlock()],
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to push the two icons a little to the center like so:
[image]

Whats the best to way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap the icons with a `Padding` widget and adjust the `padding` values accordingly. Additionally, you can use the Row widget to align the `leading` and action icons `horizontally`.

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My App'),
      leading: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          size: 24,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 24,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.more_vert,
            size: 24,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

You can adjust the padding values as needed to achieve the desired spacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `PreferredSizeWidget` to create custom appBar.

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,right:10),//adjust the padding as you want
      child: AppBar(), //or row/any widget
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Now you can use `MyAppBar` in place `appBar:MyAppBar()`.